# Possible to make a ClickStart with PostgreSQL?

Tags: cloudbees

I'm making a ClickStart for Lift 2.5 but would like for it to use PostgreSQL instead of MySQL.  But since [pgsql is implemented with a script in a job configuration page](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/PostgreSQL), it's not clear how to make that happen from a clickstart.json config file.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage no - as we don't have an integrated partners or PostgreSQL service.

That would be very nice (when we do - then you will be able to in the services section).

I like postgreSQL too - so I look forward to it.

Comment: Thanks.  Would the best alternative then be to make the Clickstart with everything else except no database, and let users add pgsql manually?

Comment: Yes, we have quite a few like that. You can even have it startup and say "hey, where is my database!" with a link to how to set it up (could be a case of simply running bees config:set command once the DB is provisioned).